# Так и не могу понять, можно ли без вопросительного знака в конце

Tags: пунктуация, интонация, вопрос

> Можете напомнить ей про меня, а то я вчера сам не успел к ней подойти?

Мне кажется, что он необходим, чтобы обозначить вопросительную интонацию начала, иначе "можете" можно вообще в другом смысле понять (напомните, если хотите). Просто Sharon говорила, что если только первая часть вопросительная, а вторая нет, то можно не ставить вопросительный знак. Но как тогда понять, что первая часть с вопросительной интонацией?

Comment: Часть с вопросительной интонацией должна быть в конце предложения. То есть делаем два простых.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Знак *необходим*, поскольку без него смысл изменяется, и вежливый вопрос превращается в нечто похожее на разрешение или снисходительное дозволение. Однако знак вопроса воспринимается здесь небезупречно в сочетании с запятой - он "запаздывает" и потому затрудняет правильное прочтение первой части (по интонации и связанному с ней смыслу), так что стоит рассмотреть вариант *заключения в скобки* второй, повествовательной части предложения.

Comment: Спасибо, Александр!

Answer (score 2):

1. Я еще раз перечитала **[правила Розенталя](https://old-rozental.online/punctuatio.php?sid=88#pp88)** по поводу вопросительного знака, но на этот раз они не показались мне убедительными.

Объяснений нет, да и примеры раскрывают тему не полностью. Среди ССП и БСП нет предложений, в которых первая часть была бы вопросительной, а вторая нет. Поэтому тема требует доработки.

2. **Посмотрела [ответы](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0&start=15) у Грамоты.ру.** И вот там они  ориентируются не на Розенталя, **а на смысл.** К примеру, рассматривается БСП: Ты заметил: лес ведь кончился. Здесь как раз только первая часть является вопросительной.

Ответ справочной службы русского языка:
Чтобы читатель смог **воспроизвести вопросительную интонацию, нужен знак вопроса**: Ты заметил? Лес ведь кончился! Можно оставить лишь восклицательный знак (такой вариант хуже): Ты заметил, лес ведь кончился!

3. Теперь о вашем предложении: ***Можете напомнить ей про меня, а то я вчера сам не успел к ней подойти?***

Это ССП, по Розенталю знак вопроса вроде бы не нужен. **Но откуда такое правило взялось, как его объяснить?**  Может быть, при сочинительной связи отношения независимые, в отличие от СПП? Но это только версия, поэтому обратимся **к смыслу**.

Это ССП, но простые предложения неоднородные, то есть тоже зависимые. Кстати, это интересный тип предложения (с формантом А ТО): **с разделительными  отношениями и альтернативной мотивацией.**  Там изображены две ситуации, одна их которых нежелательна (если не напомнить, то она может про меня забыть).  Разумеется,  **вопрос в первой части надо обозначить, он главный**, а во второй части излагается только объяснение необходимости действий.

4. Вот пример  с похожим смыслом у Грамоты.ру (хотя это СПП).

«Можно ли использовать Экотеплин без пароизоляции (?) т.к. не хочется жить в  полиэтиленовом мешке (?)» То есть нужна ли запятая, тире или что-то еще после вопросительного знака, может «т.к.» нужно начать с заглавной буквы или знак вопроса поставить в другое место?

Ответ справочной службы русского языка.
Корректное оформление: *Можно ли использовать «экотеплин» без пароизоляции, т.к. не хочется жить в «полиэтиленовом мешке»?*

Comment: Спасибо, Sharon! Тут я вроде со всем согласен в целом. :) *...одну их которых желательно избежать* — я думаю, всё-таки **одной**, согласны?

Comment: @Sharon А если это транскрипция устной речи - нуждается ли она в словесной правке? Ведь речевых ошибок нет, а что сказано, то сказано. Пояснение, добавленное к вопросу, можно, в частности, выделить в отдельное предложение.

Comment: @Артём Луговой  Артем, пока не согласна, Почему же  "одной"? Две ситуации, одну из них желательно избежать.

Comment: @Alex_ander  Вторая часть бывает разной, от этого и зависит решение о постановке знака вопроса. В данном случае это важное пояснение, оно объясняет  необходимость определенных действий, поэтому не надо его в скобки заключать. А с интонацией можно разобраться просто. Первую часть произносите с вопросительной интонацией (повышение голоса), а вторую часть просто присоединяете через небольшую паузу как самостоятельное предложение. При чтении отнесенность вопроса к первой части будет пониматься однозначно. А вообще говоря, тема ИНТЕРЕСНАЯ, ее хорошо бы проследить на примерах из классиков.

Comment: Я исходил из управления: родительного падежа с "избежать". Вы разве допускаете винительный?

Comment: Да, вы правы, там Р.п., но фразу я исправила полностью. Всё-таки она не очень ясная: там инверсия,  а глагол избежать  расположен на расстоянии от формы "одной",

Comment: Правильно, и я думаю, что так лучше. :)

Comment: *Разумеется, вопрос в первой части надо обозначить, он главный, а во второй части излагается только объяснение необходимости действий.* — Вы имеете в виду, что надо разбить на два предложения: первое вопросительное, а второе утвердительное? Правильно я понял?